# How to import a variable from a function in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, variables

I am running into some issues with importing a function. Here's the code!

## main.py

```
!/usr/bin/env python

import pyglet

class main():
    def mainfunc(self):
    # sets up user input and converts it into a string
        userinput = str(input("Please enter the full path of your     file: "))

        path = userinput
        return userinput
        music = pyglet.media.load(userinput)
        exitinput = str(input("Do you want to exit? Please press q to quit!"))
        music.play()
        pyglet.app.run()
        if exitinput == "q":
            quit()
        else:
            pass
main()
```

## Playlists.py

```
from main import mainfunc

class PlayLists:

    def playlists(self):
        playinput = str(input("Please enter a key if you want to save a playlist"))
        user = main()
        user.main(userinput)
```

Also, I have an issue with trying to exit the program on the press of a "q" button. BTW, the first line of main.py needs a pound sign. 
Thanks!

Comment: First: one question at the time. Second, there is much more wrong with your code than only the import from the other file. Therefore, first reduce the complexity of your code and see if the less complex approach has any problems, than move forward to a more complex solution if you think that is required. In this case, that means. Use only one file. Don't use any classes, you are currently using them incorrect, ie the code for them is incomplete. If you correctly have that working, you can move on by putting stuff in classes. If you have that working, you can split things in files.

Comment: I think there are more issues here than just an import. Example, `return userinput` will return and exit the function. The rest of the function will not run. I would also argue that classes are not necessary here, since there's no object-oriented paradigm that's leveraged (at least not explicitly in what you've posted)

Comment: I see no reason for you to be using a class. You never call its __init__(self): function and in fact never use and self.method functionality at all. In my opinion you should take out the `class main()` line and dedent the rest of the code in main.py such that it becomes a function

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to import a method from a class

```
from main import main

main.mainfunc() #to access your method from the class
user = main() #to create an instance of the imported class
user.mainfunc(userinput) # to get the method going
```